# how to add audio to exist video using FFMPEG at specific time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

I have video file (.avi) that 10 minutes long. I also have audio file (.wav) that is one minute long. I need to add the audio to the video, but the audio needs to start at one minute in to the video. How can I do this with ffmpeg?

I've already tried this command ( with a 30 second offset instead of one minute):

`-i video.avi -i audio.wav -filter_complex \"[1]adelay=30000|30000[aud];[0][aud]amix\" - c:v copy out.avi"`

and this one also:

`-i video.avi -i audio.wav -filter_complex [1]adelay=30000|30000[aud];[0][aud]amix - c:v copy out.avi`

But neither of them worked.

Comment: What didn't work? The audio didn't start when you wanted to? The audio didn't come through at all? Please share the full output of the commands.

Comment: I get an error from the ffmpeg process. 
the query does not work

Comment: What is the error? Please share the full command output.

Comment: Answered at Stack Overflow [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169031/how-to-add-audio-to-exist-video-using-ffmpeg-at-specific-time). Please avoid asking the same question at multiple Stack Exchange sites.